# Can't signin into microsoft account

Tags: azure, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I didn't have any problems before with signin into ms account, but now I can't get access to any account (to my account and even to new accounts) from any browser on my pc (but can signin from other pc, so, I know for sure - my account is active and havn't been blocked).

How it works (or, actually, doesn't):
1. Open https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/
2. click on "Sign in to Azure DevOps"
3. enter email and press enter
4. after few seconds and few requests (and few redirects), browser shows signin page again
OR:
1. Open https://portal.azure.com
2. enter email and press enter
3. after few seconds and few requests (and few redirects), I retrieve page "Sign-in failed. Sorry, we had some trouble signing you in, Click 'Try again' to try again."

Other details:
OS: Windows (maybe it happend after latest windows update, I'm not sure)
No installed antivirus or security software (just windows defender)
Browsers: Chrome, Edge on chromium, Firefox, Opera
It happened one week ago, and I still can't signin

There is no failed responses (4xx or 5xx), and no errors in console, so I really dont know how to fix it, maybe someone can help me with this problem

Importang thing: If I change network from my home wifi to another, I can signin there, so problem somewhere in wifi/router

Comment: Have you tried an Incognito window?

Comment: Yeah, I tried incognito in every browser, I tried clear all cache, still doesn't work...

Comment: Could you check to see what's under **Credential Manager** and, if the account is there, clear it out? You can simply open Start and type *credential manager*.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, yes, it helped, I removed all related to microsoft records, and now it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see what's under Credential Manager and, if the account is there, clear it out.

To go there, simply open Start and type `credential manager`.

[image: Credential Manager screenshot]

You should be good to go.